# Save filename.m deleted my origonal filename.m file and replaced it with a new file. How to get the old back?

Tags: matlab, save

I tried to save my file using the command window in Matlab. Unfortunately it replaced my file with a new file. And now I am unable to get it back.
It's probably easy, but I am new to using the command window in Matlab.

Comment: You'd be surprised/shocked, when you'll realize that you can't.. AKAIK

Comment: It did? No it didn't you did. Harsh lesson that isn't it. Have look at  source control. Github would be a reasonable start.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering, if i do want to be able to save the file through the command window, how should i do it so it don't  replace my file but save it?. The same way as ctrl + s.

Comment: If it replaced an .m-file that you edited in the MATLAB editor (what the title somehow suggests), you might be able to find the auto-save version of your file, which should be called "filename.asv". This file should contain a older version of your original file - simply open it in the editor. If you're lucky, it's not too old...

Comment: Are you on a Mac? Use Time Machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are out of luck on this one. Saving to a file will irretrievably overwrite any existing file with that name unless you specify otherwise with the [`-append` option](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#bt0xgur-6).  In the future, if you have a data set that is important because it is either not reproducable or because it takes a long time to generate it, I would recommend either backing it up or saving it with a timestamp. This is one example:

```
function save_t(name,varargin)
  save(sprintf('%s-%d',name,time),clock*[1e8 1e6 1e4 1e2 1 0].',varargin{:});
end
```

Save this to a file in you matlab path named "save_t.m" and then you can simply call it just like you would call the `save` function, but now it will add on a timestamp.

```
save_t filename
```

This will help to ensure that you don't accidentally overwrite an existing file.